# Magento marketplace with centralized fulfillment

Tags: marketplace, order-management

I'm new to Magento (while experienced in PHP and several frameworks) and I was asked to build a marketplace site. Mostly Amazon like.
That is, several vendors publishing their stuff for sale while all the order management (fulfilling, shipping, etc) is managed by the marketplace owner.
I saw several extensions that provide pretty much of the functionality but all of them seem to let the particular vendor manage the order and fulfillment.
Can I get some advise on an ecosystem of packages that would let me do that?
Any advise is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Would prefer 2. But I'm open to the one which results the most convenient